# angular - passing ngmodel bound to an element to a function bound to another element

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, html

I have a requirement of passing a value entered in an `input[type="text"]` element to a function `calculate()` which is bound to another element. So, whenever the value in the input field changes, the calculated values should reflect in the `Result`.

If it could be done in any other way, please let me know. Appreciated.

My Html goes as follows:

```
<tr>
    <td>Points</td>
    <td ng-repeat="score in player.scores ">
       <input type="text" ng-value="{{score.stroke}}" ng-model="???????"/>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Result</td>
    <td ng-repeat="param in cellParams >{{calculate(??????)}}</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: update your question with sample data of "player.scores" and "cellParams"

Comment: You can have watch in your ng-model of input box . from that watch, you can fire calculate().

Comment: hi, As **Alpesh Prajapati** said I have achieved this using $watch(). `$scope.$watch('player',                        
   function(newVal, oldVal) { calculate(newValue)}`  Thanks a lot Alpesh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have achieved this using $watch().

```
$scope.$watch('player', function(newVal, oldVal) { 
      calculate(newValue);
}
```

Got this answer from Alpesh's hint.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `ng-value`, when using `ng-model`... So I suppose this could just work:

```
angular.module('app', []).controller('controller', function($scope) {
    $scope.calculate = function() {
    return $scope.result = parseInt($scope.stroke) + 1;
  }
});
```

[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zLdhdvgj/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ng-keyup](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngKeyup). Whenever your input change, it will affect to your result.

An example about ng-keyup:

In html:

```
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
    <input type="text" ng-keyup="cal()" ng-model="num">
    <div>{{ result }}</div>
</div>
```

In controller:

```
angular.module('app', []).controller('ctrl', function($scope){
    $scope.cal = function()
    {
        return $scope.result = $scope.num + 1;
    }
});
```

[Code](https://jsfiddle.net/DieuNQ/n5777swL/).

Hope this help.